# How to sort array in descending order based on a specific value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of news like

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [news_published] => 1337192831
        [news_category] => 5
    )

  [1] => Array
    (
        [news_published] => 1334566743
        [news_category] => 5
    )

  [2] => Array
    (
        [news_published] => 1340092425
        [news_category] => 6
    )

  [3] => Array
    (
        [news_published] => 1339740173
        [news_category] => 6
    )

  [4] => Array
    (
        [news_published] => 1336148837
        [news_category] => 6
    )
)
```

How I can sort news_published by descending order....I have tried with 'usort' but cant find the result properly can anyone suggest me?

Comment: [uksort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php): try the first example...

Comment: post your usort() attempt, usort should work as it will use the VALUE of the elements not the key

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multidimensional-array-by-value-2

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this :

```
$arr  = your array;
$sort = array();
foreach($arr as $k=>$v) {
    $sort['news_published'][$k] = $v['news_published'];
}

array_multisort($sort['news_published'], SORT_DESC, $arr);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php


 $array = array( array('news_published'=>'1337192831','news_category'=>'5'),
            array('news_published'=>'1337192231','news_category'=>'5'),                
            array('news_published'=>'1337192921','news_category'=>'6'),

           );
  / orignal array
 print_r($array);

foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
$new_published[$key] = $row['news_published'];
 }
array_multisort($new_published, SORT_DESC,$array);

 // sorted array
print_r($array);

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or this:

```
function sortForMe($a, $b)
{
    if ((int)$a['news_published'] === (int)$b['news_published']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (int)$a['news_published'] < (int)$b['news_published'] ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($array, 'sortForMe');
```

you can use function or static method from class - your choice :)