# Sort array output

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

```
$runrwos = array();
for ($i = 0; $runrwos= mysql_fetch_assoc($run); $i++) 
{
 $DD_E_SC[$i]=$runrwos['DD_E_SC'];
 $DD_E_pKW[$i]=$runrwos['DD_E_pKW'];
 $DD_G_SC[$i]=$runrwos['DD_G_SC'];
 $DD_G_pKW[$i]=$runrwos['DD_G_pKW'];

 $data[$i] = array('DD_E_SC'=>$runrwos['DD_E_SC'],'DD_E_pKW'=>$runrwos['DD_E_pKW'], 'DD_G_SC'=>$runrwos['DD_G_SC'], 'DD_G_pKW'=>$runrwos['DD_G_pKW']);

foreach ($data as $entry) 
{
$Ep =($entry['DD_E_SC']*365+$entry['DD_E_pKW']*$SE_cons )/100;
$Gp =($entry['DD_G_SC']*365+$entry['DD_G_pKW']*$SG_cons )/100;
$Tp=$Ep+$Gp;

}
}
```

I have the above code that get row data from a database, once data are retrieved and stored into an array give the expected result.
This code work fine, but output result as retrieved from database.
My problem is when I sort the data by  $Tp or  $Ep or $Gp.
I need to sort by descendant or ascendant value.
Any help Thanks

Comment: array_multisort($sort, SORT_DESC, $arr);

Comment: array_multisort($Tp, SORT_DESC, $data);  I tried before but gives the following error: array_multisort(): Argument #1 is expected to be an array or a sort flag

Comment: It should be array by this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15476085/how-to-sort-array-in-descending-order-based-on-a-specific-value

Comment: Once I modify the data using the formula/calculation it gives result as double, and it's not an array any more. var_dump( $Tp); float()

Comment: it would be **a lot easier** to have the DB sort it for you in the SQL query.

Comment: Each query involve different variables some of them from database others from user input.